# comparing 2 files and removing lines common to both

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I have 2 files, source.txt and old.txt. Wanting to compare and remove of lines, So anything in both old.txt and source.txt, is removed from source.txt

source.txt:

```
abc.com
def.com
ghi.com
123.com
456.com
789.com
700.com
710.com
```

old.txt:

```
123.com
700.com
def.com
```

output (updated source.txt):

```
abc.com
ghi.com
456.com
789.com
710.com
```

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/066

Answer (score 1):

```bash
perl -ne'
   BEGIN { local $/; ++$remove{ $_ } for split /^/m, <> }
   print if !$remove{ $_ };
' old.txt source.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use [`grep(1)`](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/grep1.html):

```
grep -v -f old.txt source.txt
```